# Query que liste as datas

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, select

Boa noite,

Como a Query pode ficar com a seguinte ação no PostgreSQL:

**Que liste as datas que caíram no domingo dos últimos 6 meses baseado na data corrente, independente dos dados na base.**

*OBS: Os registros que estão no banco, é em formato de data, exemplo: 2017-09-10*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz a seguinte query, veja se lhe ajuda:

```
Select
    now()::date -  i 
FROM generate_series(0,6*30) i(i)
where EXTRACT('dow' from now()::date -  i) = 0
```

Explicando:

> generate_series: Gerar uma série de valores, desde o início até o fim com um tamanho de passo de um

utilizando os parâmetros, 0 e 6*30 (6 meses), será gerada uma série de 0 até 180.

agora, pegamos a data atual, e subtraímos i dias, tendo todas as datas a partir de hoje, até 180 dias atrás.

finalmente no where, filtramos somente as datas em que o dia da semana, `dow`, for igual a 0 (domingo).

links:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html

coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/4258

Comment: Nem todos os meses possuem `30 dias`, logo, nem sempre o intervalo de `6 meses` possui `180 dias`! Assumir que o mês possui sempre `30 dias` pode causar uma margem de erro de `2.5 dias` em um intervalo de `6 meses`. Segundo o Google, `1 mês` possui `30.4167 dias`! https://www.google.com.br/search?q=1+month+in+days

Answer (score 3):

Você pode gerar uma serie de datas por meio da função `generate_series()`, e depois filtrar apenas as datas que caem no domingo usando a cláusula `WHERE`.

Desde a versão `8.4` do PostgreSQL, a função `generate_series()` é capaz de gerar séries de data:

```
SELECT
    dt::date
FROM
    generate_series( now() - '6 month'::interval, now(), '1 day'::interval ) AS dt
WHERE
    EXTRACT('dow' from dt) = 0;
```

Comment: estava crente que a função só recebia inteiros, muito bacana =] vlw

Comment: O PostgreSQL evoluiu muito nos ultimos anos ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você pode utilizar essa funcao:

A função no caso retorna o dia da semana, 7 é domingo.

**data_admissao** é minha coluna que contém as datas.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM  data_admissao)

FROM tb_empregado
WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM  data_admissao) =7
```

A função: `date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '6 month')` 
irá lhe retornar a data de 6 meses atrás.

**Atualização:**
Testei aqui e você consegue filtrar da maneira que lhe informei

Segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_empregado
WHERE EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM  data_admissao) =7 
AND data_admissao <date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '6 month')

//Função responsável por retornar o dia da semana da data inserida, no caso a coluna
EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM  data_admissao)
```

Parte responsável por retornar a data atual - 6 meses

```
date_trunc('day', NOW() - interval '6 month')
```

Comment: Era isso que você precisava?

Comment: Deu certo também, vlw!